# Regular expression in Python issue. re.sub() working strangely

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

So I am attempting to use python to write text to a Microsoft word document. The code works perfectly except for when it runs up against a non-ascii character. When that happens, I am greeted by the following error.

> ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters

I'd attempted to solve this issue by using regular expressions to pluck out and replace non-ascii characters.  `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)` seemed like it it would work. Here is the code that I threw together:

```
match1 = re.search(ur'Ê¼', bodyHTML)
match2 = re.search(ur'ï¬', bodyHTML)
match3 = re.search(ur'ï¬‚', bodyHTML)
if match1:
    print 'Match 1'
    bodyHTML = re.sub(ur'Ê¼', "'", bodyHTML)
if match3:
    print 'Match 3'
    bodyHTML = re.sub(ur'ï¬‚', 'fl', bodyHTML)
if match2:
    print 'Match 2'
    bodyHTML = re.sub(ur'ï¬', 'fi', bodyHTML)
```

"match1" works perfectly. Whenever there is an Ê¼ in the text, it is replaced by an apostrophe.

"match2" and "match3" are a different story. Here's an example:

> After a short hike we had our ï¬rst glimpse of the museum

Naturally, this triggers a response from match2. But instead of producing

> After a short hike we had our first glimpse of the museum

It spits out

> After a short hike we had our fiürst glimpse of the museum

This happens several times. "signiï¬cant" becomes "signifiücant" and so on.

I am not sure why this is happening.

I am also running into an issue where match2 is steamrolling any match from match3. In other words

> the ripples on the pond and so did the shimmering reï¬‚ections in the glass walls

becomes

> the ripples on the pond and so did the shimmering refiéected in the glass walls

instead of

> the ripples on the pond and so did the shimmering reflected in the glass walls

I'm not really sure why match2 is dominating, especially because I put the match3 if statement before the one for match2 specifically so it would remove all of sections with "ï¬‚" and leave only the "ï¬" snippets for match2 to mop up.

As far as the other non-ascii characters popping up after running the code...I have no idea.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I have to strip weird characters out of data and I have much better luck using stuff like:  result = re.sub(chr(145), chr(39), result)  to change smart quotes to regular quotes.  Using the actual goofball values seems to yield weird results for me.  I just use http://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.htm to look that stuff up

Comment: You could try to use the regex char syntax instead. `stRx1 = r"\u{CA}\u{BC}"`
`stRx1 = r"\u{EF}\u{AC}"`
`stRx1 = r"\u{EF}\u{AC}\u{201A}"` To me, this looks suspicious `0201A    ‚    SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK`

Comment: @sniperd This sounds like a good idea. does it work when I link a bunch of variables together. like if I want to replace "ï¬" with "fi", do I write re.sub(chr(23)chr(172), "fi", result)?

Comment: so, I do it like this:  result = re.subn(chr(133), chr(95), text) #strange underbar   and then I have another line like that.  I'll write up a better looking example as an answer

Comment: @A. Brezel if my answer below was helpful, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

For specific 'translation' I use chr like this:

```
def process_special_characters(result):
    '''sub out known yuck for legit stuff (smart quotes, etc.), keep track of how many changes'''
    total = 0

    result = re.subn(chr(133), chr(95), result) #strange underbar
    total += result[1]
    result = re.subn(chr(145), chr(39), result[0]) #smart quote
    total += result[1]
    result = re.subn(chr(146), chr(39), result[0]) #other smart quote
    total += result[1]
    result = re.subn(chr(150), chr(45), result[0]) #strange hyphen
    total += result[1]
    result = re.subn(chr(8212), chr(45), result[0]) #strange long hyphen
    total += result[1]
    result = re.subn(chr(160), chr(32), result[0]) #non breaking space
    total += result[1]

    return result[0], total
```

You could easily make a dict and just have the key be your "from" and the value be the "to" and loop it.  If it's a short list this works fine.  Note, using subn allows you to keep track of the number of changes.  You can always just toss that all that logic and just go with sub, just that in my case the business side wanted a count of changes.

You could also have lines like this if it is easier to read:

```
result = re.subn(chr(133), "_", result) #strange underbar
```

Good luck!  Just toss a comment in if you have more questions and I'll update.